# PDO: does prepare() escape all data, even if not bound?

Tags: php, database, security, pdo, escaping

Certain data types, I.E. numbers or a table name cannot be added as a parameter with PDO, as it adds single quotes around them.

When I add them (the variables) manually, say something like this:

```
  $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME (id, foo, timestamp) VALUES (1234, ?, 4567890))");
  $statement->execute(Array($foo));
```

My question is: Does prepare() escape or properly handle ALL data within? Or *just* data that is bound by execute /parameter bind? my variable placing directly into the `prepare()` statement is rare, but I really wish to know for security when writing these.

Comment: table name **is not a "data type"** but identifier. and it has nothing to do with escaping, parametrizing and any other **data** treatment.

Comment: what numbers you are talking about? what number you are (not PDO) unable to add as a parameter?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: My mistake, I had briefly read a few people discuss that single quotes messed things up. You're right about data types! It's 7:41 in the morning (stayed up all night doing this), took a LOT longer to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: Does prepare() escape or properly handle ALL data within? Or just data that is binded by execute /parameter bind?

No. Only bound parameters are escaped.

*Always* bind parameters for *all* incoming data.

Comment: Ouch, so this makes certain escaping impossible without a fairly heavy custom function (that mimicks mysql_real_escape_string's encoding checks).. ?

Comment: @John numbers aren't a problem: Their getting enclosed in quotes doesn't hurt (plus if you want to specify a numeric type, you can use [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and specify a [data type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)). With table names, as far as I can see (and as [previously discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665784/php-pdo-prepared-statements-dont-work-when-creating-a-table)), I think yes.

Comment: Alright, I do not need to worry about table names so I'll just stick with bindParam. Thank you.

Comment: @John you HAVE to worry about table names, as well as you have to worry about bad design at all.

Comment: @Pekka: Treating numbers like strings will burn you if you switch to another DBMS later.  Or even code against another one in another app.

Comment: but a function that mimicks mysql_real_escape_string's encoding checks is a nightmare. Again, identifier is not data. And has nothing to do with mysql_real_escape_string and do not need any encoding checks

Comment: I hate such "accepted" answers, which helps nothing and only leads to another stupid questions

Comment: @R.Bemrose good point! Duly noted. @Col there was a perfectly legitimate use case for dynamic table names in the other question. I know that building applications that run under limited circumstances is beneath you, but for some people, it is not. I agree though that writing a mock escape function is horrible.

Comment: @Col: I mentioned it was way too late for me, I was able to indirectly clear 5-6 problems with an indirect answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, prepare only escapes data that uses placeholders.

Answer (score -3):

No; AFAIK $-expansion is handled directly by PHP, and `"foo $bar baz"` is equivalent to `"foo " . $bar . " baz"`.

Comment: What does this have to do with my question about adding them directly? The question was about if `prepare()` escaped including $bar, not that $bar was taken by PDO and escaped separately.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME ..."` there you have your php variable (i.e. you've opened the door for this answer ;-)) and pdo doesn't handle this. If e.g. $TABLE_NAME contains a space pdo will not  automagically quote it with grave accents.

Comment: Let's try to explain with a concrete example: if $TABLE_NAME is "foo default values; drop table foo; insert into bar", prepare() *just* sees "insert into foo default values; drop table foo; insert into bar ...". There's no way for prepare() to tell the difference between `$foo = abc; prepare("$foo")` and `prepare("abc")`.