# MySQL Create new table syntax errors

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I was trying to create a new table with the following PHP/mysql code snippet:

```
                    $query = "
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :user (
                            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            username CHAR(24),
                            summonername VARCHAR(16),
                            password VARCHAR(16),
                            region CHAR(3),
                            lvl INT(2) DEFAULT '0',
                            maxlvl INT(2),
                            status VARCHAR(20),
                            enabled INT(1) DEFAULT '1',
                            priority INT(1) DEFAULT '0',
                            note VARCHAR(150)
                        )
                    ";

                    $query_params = array (
                        ':user' => $user,
                    );
```

If I execute this one, I get some syntax error:

> Failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''testuser' ( id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, use' at line 1

It is weird because I checked the syntax according to the official documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html) and also some user-made examples. 
Also, is there a way to set the default encoding of the table to utf8 (not for every single row, but global)?

I would be happy if someone can tell me how to fix the syntax errors there,

Comment: You can't use parameters for identifiers like table or column names.

Comment: as @VMai said, you can´t use identifiers on create table. But you have this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665784/php-pdo-prepared-statements-dont-work-when-creating-a-table

Comment: And I'm sure INT(1)/INT(2) don't mean whatever you think they mean!

Comment: INT(1) is a 1 character int...!? Like, a number with the length of 1 character. I'm aware that it is not 1 but can be 0-9

Comment: @Strawberry's right: The value range of such columns is -2147483648 up to 2147483647  ... *The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly.* Source: [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Comment: So, what is the point of writing it then? Or is there any other way to set the range/length of values?

Comment: It only really makes sense in the context of ZEROFILL. But seeing as padding can achieve exactly the same thing, it doesn't make a lot of sense there either.

Comment: I never use the display width. Checking ranges with current MySQL: you could use triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for metadata. Nor should you be creating tables per user. Either add a field to hold the user, or sanitize the table name yourself.

Comment: Okay, so that's why it is throwing an error. But how can I create tables with variable names? // Because I kinda need to create tables for many different users. // I'm aware that this is not the correct way to store the users of the web site... They are stored in another (single) table obviously

Comment: Same way you replace variables into every other string in PHP; there's nothing special about SQL queries that prevents you from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to my comment above, and by way of example...

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table(i INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1),(9),(10),(99),(100),(999),(1000),(9999),(10000);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +-------+
 | i     |
 +-------+
 |  0001 |
 |  0009 |
 |  0010 |
 |  0099 |
 |  0100 |
 |  0999 |
 |  1000 |
 |  9999 |
 | 10000 |
 +-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this query in create table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
                        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        username CHAR(24),
                        summonername VARCHAR(16),
                        password VARCHAR(16),
                        region CHAR(3),
                        lvl INT(2) DEFAULT '0',
                        maxlvl INT(2),
                        status VARCHAR(20),
                        enabled INT(1) DEFAULT '1',
                        priority INT(1) DEFAULT '0',
                        )
```