# mysqli->prepare issue with creating tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a table with `mysqli->prepare`, but get an error while preparing the statement.
My statement is as follows:

```
$mysqli->prepare("CREATE TABLE ? (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))");
```

Then I just bind the table name to it

```
$mysqli->bind_param("s", $some_name);
```

And execute it.

```
$mysqli->execute();
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KE' at line 1
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what is the value of $some_name ?

Comment: just a string like "table1"

Answer (score 2):

See 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

> In general, parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Comment: Could i do this with pdo prepared statements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665784/php-pdo-prepared-statements-dont-work-when-creating-a-table

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been answered before. [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)
You can't bind the table name