# How to use SQL REVOKE, GRANT and ALTER commands as prepared statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to create a web based MySQL user management console and I'm struggling to successfully execute the REVOKE, GRANT and ALTER commands as prepared statements in PHP.

Could someone please give me an example of the following SQL statement being executed in PHP as a prepared statement.

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'TestUser'@'%'

I'm trying

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM ?@?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", "TestUser", "host");
$stmt->execute();
```

I am getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Comment: So please show us the code you are having issues with

Comment: And what errors are you getting??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited it to include some code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool, the syntax is clearly incorrect but I can't find the correct syntax anywhere.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3665849/231316

Comment: Yea, dont think the compiler would like not knowing the user and domain. Works if you do it as a `->query()` with all info provided

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I mean I could use regular string concatenation but that would give rise to SQL injection issues wouldn't it

Comment: It could do, depends upon where you get the info from.